# How can I conditionally apply backgrounds to cells in Kendo Vue?

Tags: vue.js, kendo-ui

I need to apply a background to certain cells in a specific column but not the other columns. It seems this functionality is not made for Vue.

The link below shows me how to do it for an entire row but does not help me apply it to cells that meet a certain condition.

https://www.telerik.com/kendo-vue-ui/components/excel-export/api/CellOptions/

Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Stackblitz solution](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dhtsx9?file=src%2Fmain.vue)

The cells in a row are indexed according to their column, so you just have to go through the cells of each row and only target the cells with index equal to the column you want to work with.

```js
import { workbookOptions, toDataURL } from '@progress/kendo-vue-excel-export';
import { saveAs } from '@progress/kendo-file-saver';
import products from './products.json';


data: function () {
  return {
    columns: [
      { field: 'ProductID' },
      { field: 'ProductName', title: 'Product Name' },
      { field: 'UnitsInStock', title: 'Units in Stock' },
    ],
  };
},

methods: {
  exportExcel() {
    this.customSaveExcel({
      data: products,
      fileName: 'myFile',
      columns: this.columns,
    });
  },
  customSaveExcel: function (exportOptions) {
    const saveFn = (dataURL) => {
      saveAs(dataURL, exportOptions.fileName);
    };

    const options = workbookOptions(exportOptions);
    const rows = options.sheets[0].rows;

    /*  Color all cells with stock >= 20 as green
     *  Color all cells with stock < 20 && > 0 as yellow
     *  Color all cells with stock === 0 as red
     */
    rows.forEach((row) => {
      if (row.type === 'data') {
        let unitsCell = row.cells[2]; // column 3 "UnitsInStock" is index 2
        if (unitsCell.value >= 20) unitsCell.background = '#22ff00';
        else if (unitsCell.value < 20 && unitsCell.value > 0)
          unitsCell.background = '#fff700';
        else if (unitsCell.value === 0) unitsCell.background = '#ef0000';
      }
    });
    toDataURL(options).then(saveFn);
  },
},
```

Comment: This worked! Where did you find this code on the kendo website?

Comment: I looked at [this example](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-vue-ui/components/excel-export/customization/) and modified it myself